# boolean order attribute won't save correctly in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, sales-order, setup-script

I have created my boolean order attribute

```
/* @var $installer \Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();


$smsAttribute = [
    'type' => 'int',
    'label' => 'Tracking SMS Status',
    'input' => 'boolean',
    'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => false, //true/false
    'default' => 0,
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'user_defined' => true,
];

$installer->addAttribute(
    'order',
    Vendor_SmsTracking_Helper_Data::ATTRIBUTE_SMS_STATUS,
    $smsAttribute
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

And I can see it's correctly created in the database table

I've added the following config

```
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>
                <myattributecode><to_order>*</to_order></myattributecode>
            </sales_convert_quote>

            <sales_convert_order>
                <myattributecode><to_quote>*</to_quote></myattributecode>
            </sales_convert_order>
        </fieldsets>
```

Finally I try to change the flag on the order like this to test

```
<?php

require('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
$orderIncrementId = '<myincrementid>';

Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
/** @var \Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order */
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
echo $order->getId();
$order->setData('myattributecode', 1); //fails
$order->setData('myattributecode', true); //fails
$order->save(); //fails to save it
$order->getResource()->saveAttribute($order, 'myattributecode'); //fails to save as well
```

However the attribute is never saved and stays at the default value of 0.

Any ideas why?

Comment: hi there, in what scope are you declaring the custom attribute?

Comment: I'm using Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL

Comment: no, i mean in your config.xml file :) the node under which you added the `<fieldsets>` node.

Comment: oh OK, under global

Comment: hi there, did you solve this?

Comment: Not exactly, the code seems valid but something else is going on preventing the save. I noticed that there was an error in index process which prevented the attribute for being saved completely. After that the sample above worked. This piece of code however was in reality used on an event observer when a shipment was saved but was executed twice. So I was trying to prevent this double execution.

Comment: My flag would not be saved on the first trigger but it would on the second trigger so I can only think that another observer is keeping the order data state, and saving above my save event. I can't find any other valid reason for it to happen. Finally I ended up using registry to prevent my second action from occuring.

Comment: i see.. what i suggest in this situation is to use a debugger and see the exact process flow and trace. maybe you need a custom event to be triggered at a place you need it or maybe you need to swap to another Magento event. the code which added the attribute and how it was used seemed ok to me.

Comment: I've been debugging the application and I couldn't find the flow which causes the issue so it's only an assumption. I'll probably need a full trace of the executions to see what's in between my function calls